# JavaFX UI Freezes in JavaFX Application Thread in Event Listener but works with Platform.runLater

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

In my JavaFX program, I currently have all my code running on the JavaFX Application Thread (including game logic code that does not necessarily update the UI). I've read that you should run non-UI code in a separate background thread and then update it accordingly in the JavaFX Application Thread using `Platform.runLater` or `Tasks`, so that the UI is not blocked, but I'm still confused as to why the UI freezes when I simply call `myFlowPane.getChildren().remove()` on the JavaFX Application Thread.

The following code hopefully provides enough context

```
hand.getTiles().addListener((ListChangeListener<ObservableTile>) change -> {
    while (change.next()) {
        if (change.wasAdded()) {
            for (Tile t : change.getAddedSubList()) {
                var btn = tileButtonFactory.newTileButton(t);
                fpHand.getChildren().add(change.getFrom(), btn);
            }
        } else if (change.wasRemoved()) {
            // Player can only remove 1 tile at a time
            Tile tile = change.getRemoved().get(0);
            fpHand.getChildren().removeIf(node -> ((TileButton)node).getTile().equals(tile));
        }
    }
});
```

I have a FlowPane that contains a bunch of buttons, and I'm listening on an `ObservableList` that contains a bunch of tiles. When this list of tiles changes, I want to update the FlowPane accordingly so that any new tiles, I create a button in the FlowPane. Similarly, when a tile is removed from this list of tiles, I want the button that contains this Tile to be removed from the FlowPane.

So from what I found online, event listeners run on the JavaFX Application Thread. This means that the code above is running on the JavaFX Application thread. When I add a button to my FlowPane, the UI does *not* freeze/get blocked `fpHand.getChildren().add()`. On the other hand, when I remove a button from the FlowPane, the UI freezes on `fpHand.getChildren.remove`.

However, when I wrap the `fpHand.getChildren.remove()` call with a `Platform.runLater()`, the UI is responsive and doesn't freeze. Why is this? All the code is currently running on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Also, I have a similar problem with another part of my code. I have a GridPane with 128 cells (which each cell has an HBox) and I need to update the table. I have the following code:

```
private void updateTable() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        clearTable();
        table.forEach(this::addTilesToTable);
    });
}
private void clearTable() {
    for (int row = 0; row < gpTable.getRowCount(); row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < gpTable.getColumnCount(); col++) {
            getCellFromGridPane(row, col).ifPresent(hbox -> hbox.getChildren().clear());
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove the `Platform.runLater()`, the UI doesn't freeze completely, but any tiles I've added previously in the spot, it's as if there's an invisible tile there on the table, and hence I cannot add a tile there, even though it should be empty. The `updateTable()` function is also called in the JavaFX Application Thread, and in an event listener. It seems as if the `hbox.getChildren.clear()` isn't being called properly if I remove `Platform.runLater()`.

Comment: To check if the listener is called on the FX thread, use `Platform.isFxApplicationThread`. Listeners (e.g. `InvalidationListener`, `ChangeListener`, `ListChangeListener`, etc...) are called _on whichever `Thread` made the change_.  That said, have you tried debugging/profiling your application to see where it gets stuck? Even some simple print statements might tell you if you're entering a loop. If you're still unable to figure out what's wrong you'll need to provide a [mcve]; the code you provide does not give enough context.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was that I was using `setMouseTransparent(true)` for the root panes that hold the buttons containing the Tile for click and drag and not consume mouse events.

```
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
        root.setMouseTransparent(true);
        dragContext.setMouseX(e.getSceneX());
        dragContext.setMouseY(e.getSceneY());
        dragContext.setInitialTranslateX(node.getTranslateX());
        dragContext.setInitialTranslateY(node.getTranslateY());
        e.consume();
    });
```

And when you release the mouse, it sets it back to false

```
    node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED, e -> {
        root.setMouseTransparent(false);
        node.setTranslateX(0);
        node.setTranslateY(0);
        e.consume();
    });
```

The problem here was that when I remove the button from the scene, it destroys all event handlers, and even though i release the mouse, it doesn't run this code.